# How to fix empty results from variables sent to php with api?

Tags: php

I am sending 2 variables from HTML form to php json decoding from api url but I got empty values.

```
<form action="2.php" method="post">
Word: <input type="text" name="q">
<input type="hidden" name="langpair" value="en|it">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

to php file

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://api.mymemory.translated.net/get?q=<? echo $_POST["q"]; ?>;&langpair=<? echo $_POST["langpair"]; ?>');
$obj = json_decode($json);

echo $obj->responseData->translatedText;
```

I am getting empty page!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons, you should not pass the variables directly to the url, but if you want to do it should be like this:

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://api.mymemory.translated.net/get?q='.urlencode($_POST["q"]).'&langpair='.urlencode($_POST["langpair"]));
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because of your URL! Change it for this :

```
file_get_contents('https://api.mymemory.translated.net/get?q=' . $_POST["q"]. '&langpair=' . $_POST["langpair"]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this syntax did not work, please see the other answer of @EmilianoT thank you anyway.